# erro com insert e mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-insert

tenho o seguinte metodo:

```
 public byte[] CarregarArquivoImagem( Int64 idVenda,string nomeArquivo, string caminhoArquivo, int ImagemTamanhoMaximo)
    {
        string query = null;
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        byte[] imagemBytes = null;

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ClassMaster.mysqlConection().ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {                    
                MySqlParameter imagem01 = new MySqlParameter();
                imagem01.ParameterName = "@imagem01";
                imagem01.Value = "imagem01";
                imagem01.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;

                MySqlParameter imagem02 = new MySqlParameter();
                imagem02.ParameterName = "@imagem02";
                imagem02.Value = "imagem02";
                imagem02.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;

                query = "INSERT INTO venda_imagem (id, venda_id_venda, imagem_cupom, imagem_receita) VALUES('21121242132', 69," +
                    "@imagem01,@imagem02)";

                con.Open();

                cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                con.Close();

                return imagemBytes;
            }
            catch (MySqlException exx)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return imagemBytes;
    }
```

esta retornando o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.

no InnerException retorna o seguinte:

```
Parameter '@imagem01' must be defined.
```

o que esta errado?, o parâmetro foi definido, nao consigo entender onde esta o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo um exemplo em https://zetcode.com/csharp/mysql/ você precisa adicionar os parâmetros ao comando. Tirado do exemplo:

```
        var sql = "INSERT INTO cars(name, price) VALUES(@name, @price)";
        using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "BMW");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 36600);
        cmd.Prepare();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: fiz como sugerido, deu o mesmo erro, estou usando .net core, será q pode ser um bug?